# what's the wrong when we use Euclid logic to prove the twin prime conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

what's the wrong when we use Euclid logic to prove the twin prime conjecture ?
$$Q1=p1*p2*p3*.....*pn+1$$
$$Q2=p1*p2*p3*.....*pn-1$$
where: $$Q1-Q2=2$$

Euclid's proof considers any finite set S of primes

Comment: Neither $Q_1$ nor $Q_2$ need be prime. (You should review carefully how Euclid's proof that there are infinitely primes goes.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because we don't know when $Q_1$ or $Q_2$ will be primes.

A subtle point is Euclid's proof of infinite primes constructs  $Q1 = p_1*p_2*p_3*.... p_n + 1$ and proves that none of $p_i|Q_1$.  But the (correct[$*$]) proof *NEVER* states that $Q_1$ is prime-- it just states that $p_1,......, p_n$ can not be *all* the primes. Because none of them divide $Q_1$ an there must be *another* prime that *does*.  But *NOWHERE* is it stated or assumed that that other prime is actually $Q_1$.

Indeed $2×3×5×7×11×13+1=30031=59\times 509$ is not prime.

But we *can* conclude that there must be *another* prime $q$ so that $p_i < q \le Q_1$ and $q|Q_1$.

And in the above example $13 < 59 < 2×3×5×7×11×13+1$.  So $2,3,5,7,11,13$ can't be *all* the primes; there must be a prime greater than $13$.  And there is $59$.

[$*$]  Bad versions of the proof often state "Assume $p_1... p_n$ are *all* the primes.  Then $Q_1$ is prime *because no prime divides it* (because there *are* not other primes than $p_1,..., p_n$).  Thus a contradiction.

But that only proves $Q_1$ is prime ***IF*** we assume that $p_1....p_n$ are all the primes.  THey are not! And we have *not* proven $Q_1$ is prime.  We have not proven *anything* about $Q_1$ except that none of $p_1,...., p_n$ do not divide it.  But since $p_1,....., p_n$ are *NOT* all the primes that isn't very significant.

After an $2, 3 ,5, 7$ do not divide $11*13= 143$.  That certainly does *not* mean $143$ is prime.  (Although it would ***IF*** $2,3,5$ and $7$ were *all* the primes.  But that would be a contradiction.  So I have proven there is a prime larger than $7$.  ....  Good for me....)

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with a variant of Euclid's proof where you conclude $Q_1$ or $Q_2$ are prime, then you're doing a proof by contradiction under the assumption that $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ is the *complete* list of primes. In fact, making this conclusion at all is somewhat silly: what we really conclude is that $Q_1$ is not divisible by any of the primes in our list, and thus must have a prime factor not in our list. This is already a contradiction. You can take a logically correct argument further and conclude that $Q_1$ is prime, but the same is true of any claim you wish (since we already have a contradiction), so there's not much point.

Comment: Q1 and Q2 are primes!! what's wrong exactely ?

Comment: @Adbeljalil: $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 + 1 = 30031 = 59 \times 509.$

Comment: but Euclid's proof considers any finite set S of primes, so why you go to calculate when this S does not exist in your calculation (your calculation are based on the real envirement that there are infinite prime number)

Comment: Euclid give his proof based on the fact of the set of prime is finite,

Comment: @Adbeljalil: because your question is about the "real environment". If you asking about the "environment" where we assume there are finitely many primes, then the Euclid's proof shows the system is inconsistent, so every statement is both true and false by the principle of explosion.

Comment: Not taking no for an answer.

Comment: @Randall explain more!!!

Comment: @Anthony: Your analysis of Euclid's proof is incorrect. It is not really a proof by contradiction. It shows that given any list of primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ there is another prime that is not in that list - this is a constructive argument. However, that argument does **not** claim that $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdots p_n + 1 $ is prime, but rather that it has a prime factor that is not one of the $p_i$.

Comment: @RobArthan great ... this is what i mean (my english level is bad)

Comment: @RobArthan: you're right, I was sloppy. I usually talk about the proof as one by contradiction not out of logical necessity, but because it's how it is most frequently taught in my experience, and because it's how most students come to the incorrect conclusion that $Q_1$ is a prime. Technically we can write a contradiction argument that concludes $Q_1$ is prime, but of course by this stage we're deep into explosion land already so it's silly (and missing the main point).

Comment: The proof (might) state that $Q_1$ is prime *IF*  $p_1, ..... , p_n$ are *all* the primes that exist in the universe.  But $p_1,...., p_n$ are not all the primes that exist in the universe, we can not conclude $Q_1$ is prime.  Indeed all we can conclude is that there is a prime $q$ so that $p_n < q \le Q_1$ and $q|Q_i$.  $q$ *might* be $Q_1$.  Or it might not be.  If $Q_1 = 2*3*5*7*11*13+1$ then $q \ne Q_1$.  $q = 59$.

Comment: @fleablood: right, this is a good explanation of the flaw in the OP's reasoning. In the setting of a proof by contradiction, the fact that $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are all the primes in the universe is an assumption, and thus true; so we can conclude $Q_1$ is prime and use this as our final contradiction if we wish. It's silly, but legal.

Comment: We can only assume it is true *while* we assume it is true.  Once we prove it is false we can't assume that.  And anything we proved along the way can not be kept, because they were all based on false assumptions.  When we "proved" $Q_1$ was prime, it was under the assumption that $p_1,... p_n$ were all the primes.  *While* we were assuming that was true we could claim we proved $Q_1$ was prime, but once we *stop* assuming that, we can't.

Comment: Example: Prove $5$ is not a square. Pf: assume it is then $25=5^2=k^4$  $4>3$.  Therefore there exists a perfect cube that divides $25$. The only prime factor of $25$ is $5$ so $5^3|25$ but $5^3=125>25$ which is a contradiction. QED.  Well, along the way, we proved that there is a perfect cube that divides $25$.  Now that my proof is done I can't claim that there is a perfect cube that divides $25$ even though I "proved" it.  It was based on a false premise.  So was the proof that $Q_1$ was prime.

Comment: Of course you can't claim it as a truth in the outer ("true") universe, I never said this.

Comment: @fleablood i want to say: if the Euclid logic is true so will be true for the twin prime conjecture, i want to say that math is based on "assuming" what we want to assume (it's not important what you assume the most important that will not create a contradiction inside (o implies 1 is true and 0 implies 0 also true)

Comment: Of course, but concluding $Q_1$ was prime didn't use "Euclid logic".  It was a step *INSIDE* a proof by contradiction based upon *FALSE* premises.  The only universe in which it is true is one in which there are only finitely many primes.  And we proved that that universe is not consistent and not acceptable.  We are no longer *IN* that universe.  So it is *NOT* true.  ... to be continued...

Comment: ... cont. ... I can assume in a proof by contradiction that in a universe where ducks are mammals, I can prove something reasonable, say, that ducklings huddle together for warmth, and then I notice that I've shown that 27 is prime, I realize the universe isn't valid.  I can no long accept that ducklings huddle together for warmth.  That was proven based on the assumptions ducks were mammals.  We are no longer in that universe and we can not accept that any more.  So the proof.... never happened.  ..... to be continued...

Comment: ...cont.  .... Bottom line $Q_1 = p_1*.... p_n + 1$ may or may not be prime but there is no way to tell if we don't know if any of the $p_n < p_{n+ k } < Q_1$ divide into $Q_1$.  In our "proof" we never even *thought* about $p_n < p_{n+k} < Q_1$ because in our temporary universe $p_{n+k}$ did not exist.  But we discovered our temporary universe had problems.  So we are not in that universe any more.  And $p_{n+k}$ *do* exist.